# Slick-slider progressbar and fraction don't calculate correctly 'slidesToShow' value more than 1

Tags: jquery, slick.js

When I have slidesToShow: 1, then the progressbar indicator and numbers in the fraction work correctly, if instead of 1 add 2, 3 and more to slidesToShow, then the progressbar indicator and fraction numbers do not take this into account, and it turns out when the progressbar indicator is almost full and the slides have already gone into the second round, with a fraction of a similar problem
[progressbar indicator doesn't see 3 slides on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaSYz.jpg)
[fraction first number doesn't see 3 slides on the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh2Wt.jpg)

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
            <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
            <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
            <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
            <div class="slide">Slide 4</div>
            <div class="slide">Slide 5</div>
            <div class="slide">Slide 6</div>
            <div class="slide">Slide 7</div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="slider-nav">
            <button class="prev-slide">Previous</button>
            <div class="progress-container">
                <div class="progressbar"></div>
            </div>
            <span class="fraction"></span>
            <button class="next-slide">Next</button>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slider {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
}

.slider-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.progress-container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

.progressbar {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.fraction {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider').slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    customPaging: function(slider, i) {
      return '<button class="tab">' + (i + 1) + '</button>';
    }
  });

  $('.prev-slide').click(function(){
    $('.slider').slick('slickPrev');
  });

  $('.next-slide').click(function(){
    $('.slider').slick('slickNext');
  });

  $('.slider').on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    $('.fraction').text((nextSlide + 1) + '/' + slick.slideCount);
    var progress = (nextSlide + 1) / slick.slideCount * 100;
    $('.progressbar').css('width', progress + '%');
  });

  $('.fraction').text('1/' + $('.slider').slick('getSlick').slideCount);
  var slideCount = $('.slider').slick('getSlick').slideCount;
  var progress = (1 / slideCount) * 100;
  $('.progressbar').css('width', progress + '%');
});
```